# Не понимаю как убрать отступы из за того что я вставляю картинку

Tags: html, css

```css
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.container {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

@gray-darker: #444444;
@gray-dark: #696969;
@gray: #999999;
@gray-light: #cccccc;
@gray-lighter: #ececec;
@gray-lightest: lighten(@gray-lighter, 4%);
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

body {
  color: @gray;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" on;
}

.btn {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid @gray-light;
  //border-radius: 1rem;
  color: @gray-dark;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.btn--block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.cards__item {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
  @media(min-width: 40rem) {
    width: 50%;
  }
  @media(min-width: 56rem) {
    width: 33.3333%;
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  box-shadow: 0 20px 40px -14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
  &:hover {
    .card__image {
      filter: contrast(100%);
    }
  }
}

.card__content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.card__image {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.25rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.25rem;
  filter: contrast(70%);
  //filter: saturate(180%);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  transition: filter 0.5s cubic-bezier(.43, .41, .22, .91);
  ;
  &::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-top: 56.25%; // 16:9 aspect ratio
  }
  @media(min-width: 40rem) {
    &::before {
      padding-top: 66.6%; // 3:2 aspect ratio
    }
  }
}

.card__image--flowers {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/600?image=82);
}

.card__image--river {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/600?image=11);
}

.card__image--record {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/600?image=39);
}

.card__image--fence {
  background-image: url(https://unsplash.it/800/600?image=59);
}

.card__title {
  color: @gray-dark;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card__text {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.c {
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="cards">
  <li class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">

      <div class="card__image card__image--fence">

      </div>

      <div class="card__content">
        <img src="2c.png" alt="" class="c">
        <div class="card__title">Flex</div>
        <p class="card__text">This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default is 0 1 auto. </p>
        <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image card__image--river"></div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <div class="card__title">Flex Grow</div>
        <p class="card__text">This defines the ability for a flex item to grow if necessary. It accepts a unitless value that serves as a proportion. It dictates what amount of the available space inside the flex container the item should take up.</p>
        <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__item">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card__image card__image--record"></div>
      <div class="card__content">
        <div class="card__title">Flex Shrink</div>
        <p class="card__text">This defines the ability for a flex item to shrink if necessary. Negative numbers are invalid.</p>
        <button class="btn btn--block card__btn">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="cards__item">
    < </div>
```

Не понимаю как убрать отступы из за того что я вставляю картинку

Comment: О каких отступах речь?

Comment: Если убрать каринку то все карточки будут нормальными и одинаковыми,а тут от вверха то  текста появляется пустота огромная,причем это на всех карточках сказывается по разному,хотя добавляю только на одну

Comment: Можете например для элемента `.card__item` повесить `align-items: flex-start;`